# Tips for technical animation of a watch

Tags: modeling

my first post here so thanks for you patience and the general question I am asking. I want to go into Blender to add some some 3d animations to my works.

I would like to be able to do the kind of animation you find in this link at video chapter 4 at 00:15 (gongs animation):

https://www.patek.com/en/company/technews/the-sky-moon-tourbillon-ref-6002

What do I have to have available to create such an animation? What should I ask to the client to create this? I am looking for someone who can guide and advise me. Thank you so much!

Luca - http://www.videoprod.ch

Comment: It's pretty simple, you need to parent the 2 little hammers to the watch, put their origin at their rotation center, then make them rotate

Comment: @moonboots In fact, I don't find those timings very convincing.. I think there would be a slower wind-up and a quicker release. I would ask for a video of the mechanism in action.

Comment: maybe, i'm not a specialist, i was just talking feasability wise in Blender, then I guess you need to play with the graph editor curves?

Comment: Thanks but what should I ask to the client? a video? an raw technical animation? Thanks  a Lot Luca

Comment: @Videoprod.ch, well, the more information you get from your client, the better it is, generally.